Inferentials in Non-hypothesis Testing Research. How fitting?
If a researcher conducted a research study with research questions, of course, but no hypotheses to test, would it be fine to carry out inferential statistics, e.g., a correlation test, a Kruskal-Wallis test, etc., maybe to add to the significance of the study? How harmful would it be to do so if it was adjudged not fine?

Both types of tests you name involve hypotheses. What does "adjudged not fine" mean?

@BryanKrause it means that if it was decided by participants in this discussion that it would not be fine to perform these statistical analyses in such a situation.

I don't see how anyone could judge harm without understanding the situation, and the situation as you describe it does not make much sense.

@BryanKrause others do, though.

Others do judge harm without understanding the situation? Well, good for them, then.

@BryanKrause a normal guy would get the situation if they read the post well. How non-normanl of you! Unbelievable!

I am sorry, but i to do not understand your question. If you perform the test you mention, then you have hypotheses, but you claim to have no hypotheses. Those two statements cannot both be true. Also who is judging you? A random person on the street, a teacher grading your work, a reviewer. The harm depends on the situation, and if you don't tell us, then we cannot help you.

I can guess what the situation might be, but I cannot "get" it from what you have written. As Maarten and I have each pointed out, you are naming tests that involve hypotheses; one possibility is that the situation is you do not understand what a hypothesis is. Another possibility is that the situation is that you do not understand what these tests are. Yet another possibility is that you mean these tests were not pre-planned (that is, no a priori hypotheses), but after looking at the data you have some hypotheses to test - this would be a common situation but not clearly described.

I voted to close for "needs clarity or details". I agree with the other comments here that although we can guess what you probably mean (exploratory study done with no specific hypotheses, now you want to do statistical tests of some hypotheses, probably developed by looking at the responses), we don't know that --  asking you to edit and improve your question is better than guessing. (Also, the "adjudged not fine" part is extremely unclear, I couldn't guess what that meant ...) (Also, insulting people who are trying to understand what you're asking is not helpful ...)


If a researcher conducted a research study with research questions, of
course, but no hypotheses to test, would it be fine to carry out
inferential statistics, e.g., a correlation test, a Kruskal-Wallis
test, etc.,

Statistical tests test a hypothesis. So even if you say you don't have a hypothesis, you still do when you perform a test. So the statement "I don't have a hypothesis" and "I performed a test" just don't go together.

maybe to add to the significance of the study?

The word significance has many meanings. You probably hear about significance in relation to test. That has absolutely nothing to do with the significance (importance) of a study. It is a highly technical and very limited concept. I teach this stuff right now, and if any of my students would utter that sentence then that would be a HUGE red flag. It would tell me they understood nothing about what I tried to teach them, and I would have to start over again.

How harmful would it be to do so if it was adjudged not fine?

When you report about your research you build an argument: This is what I want to know, this is how and where I have looked, this is what I have seen, and therefore I think this and that is a likely answer to my question. If you perform a statistical test, it becomes part of that argument. What you have told us, tells us very clearly that you don't understand what a statistical test is. So you don't understand your own argument. That does not build confidence in your argument...
As to the consequences, that depends on the role of the person who is reading your report:

If I were to read that report as reader, I would probably stop reading that report and dismiss it as something written by someone who does not know what they are doing.

If I am on a committee deciding whether or not to hire you and you submitted that report as a recent publication, then that mistake would probably cost you my vote (depending on the level of the job).

If I were to read that report as a reviewer, I would recommend that that paper be rejected

If I were to read that report as a teacher, I would stop reading and invite the student to my office hours and explain why I am not grading that and invite them to resubmit with an appropriate subtraction of points.


